# elasticsearch : make a should into a filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I would want to do search with a filter that exclude result that not match a condition OR anothor condition:

I tried to do a should into a filter but it fails:

```
POST /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "type1_title": "searched match"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "type2_title": "searched match"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

it raises that error:

```
 "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[should] query malformed, no start_object after query name",
        "line": 9,
        "col": 21
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[should] query malformed, no start_object after query name",
    "line": 9,
    "col": 21
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Do you know if we can do an or in a filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply `bool/should`, there's no need for `filter` here

```
POST /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
          "minimum_should_match": 1,
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "type1_title": "searched match"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "type2_title": "searched match"
              }
            }
          ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you really want to keep the `bool/filter/should` construct then you need to do it like this:

```
POST /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
         "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "type1_title": "searched match"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "type2_title": "searched match"
              }
            }
          ]
         }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, you are right but i gave a simple exemple . I really  want  to do an or in a filter . Do you know if it is a feature?

Comment: `should` is an OR filter

Comment: I've updated my answer if you really want to keep the filter