# How wrap a bool query should clause in a bool query filter clause with Object Initializer Syntax?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to do a should in a filter for having result if it match with a condition or another condition.

In elasticsearch it would be:

```
POST /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
         "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "type1_title": "searched match"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "type2_title": "searched match"
              }
            }
          ]
         }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to  enter en boolQuery in another boolQuery in nest:

```
    var shouldForFilter = new List<QueryContainer>();
     shouldForFilter.Add(new TermQuery()
     {
           Field = "type1Title", Value = "searched match",
     });
     shouldForFilter.Add(new TermQuery()
     {
           Field = "type2Title", Value = "searched match",
     });

      var shouldContainer = new List<QueryContainer> {
         ....

     }   
     ...
     var innerFilterQuery = new BoolQuery
     {
           Should = shouldForFilter
     };

  var searchQuery = new BoolQuery
  {    
       Filter = innerFilterQuery, //does not work
       Should = shouldContainer,
       Must =   mustContainer,
       From =   10,
       Size =   20
       Minscore = 1
  };
```

obviously types don't not match.

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: The query is not correct, you should take the one that you accepted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276927/elasticsearch-make-a-should-into-a-filter ;-)

Comment: yes, thank you, I fixed it

Comment: But you are missing the surrounding bool/filter now :-)

Comment: yes sorry , hard day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With operator overloading in NEST, this can be very succinctly expressed

```
client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
    .Query(q => +(q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field("type1Title")
            .Query("searched match")
        ) || q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field("type2Title")
            .Query("searched match")
        ))
    )
);
```

which produces

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "type1Title": {
                    "query": "searched match"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "type2Title": {
                    "query": "searched match"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can also use operator overloading with Object Initializer syntax, which may be a little more succinct than wrapping in `bool` queries. The important part is to apply the operations in the correct order. This example produces the same query as above

```
QueryContainer query = new MatchQuery
{
    Field = "type1Title",
    Query = "searched match"
};

// use binary || operator to wrap combined queries
// into bool query should clause
query |= new MatchQuery
{
    Field = "type2Title",
    Query = "searched match"
};

// use unary operator to wrap query in bool
// query filter clause
query = +query;

var request = new SearchRequest<MyDocument>
{
    Query = query
};

client.Search<MyDocument>(request);
```

Comment: thank you but I would like to do that without fluent write cause i want to cdynamically ombine a filter with other feature like Should, Must, highlight, Size...